# How to populate two tables in a dataset using data adapter with a single join statement?

Tags: sql, ado.net, dataset, oledb, dataadapter

What I would like to essentially do is run a query such as:

```
 select a.*, b.* 
 from a 
 left outer join b on a.col2 = b.col2 
 where a.col1 = 3
```

And get a dataset with two tables 'a' and 'b' populated.

For example if return values from query are:

```
a.col1 | a.col2 | b.col2 | b.col3
---------------------------------
3      | 33     | 33     | 1
3      | 33     | 33     | 2
```

I'd like to have these 2 tables:

```
a.col1 | a.col2
---------------
3      | 33

b.col2 | b.col3
---------------
33     | 1
33     | 2
```

Is it possible to do at all, or will I need to read the 'a' table first, then generate query for 'b' table filtering on the value of a.col2?

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by `Executing multiple SQL statements as one against SQL Server`
put your both query in a string Variable and place `;` after first query

```
string _query ="select a.* from a where a.col1 = 3; Select b.* form b";  

  using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(_query, connectionString))
    {

        /* Use DataAdapter to fill DataSet*/
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        a.Fill(ds);


    }
```

**Note:**     By using following query You will get one result set because you are join two tables into a single result set

```
select a.*, b.* 
from a 
 left outer join b on a.col2 = b.col2 
 where a.col1 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use stored procedure  to retrieve the result of two tables as one table

store your result in one dataset and reflect it where ever you want .
//stored procedure
create procedure spleftjoin
 @i int
 as
 begin
  select a.*, b.* 
  from a 
 left outer join b on [a.col2] = [b.col1]
 where [a.col1] = @i
 end
//i is the parameter for a.col1 
asp.net code drag a text box to enter the a.col1 digit and gridview control and a button . copy the code for button control click event
 protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBox.Text == "")
        {
            Response.Write("please enter a digit");
        }
        else
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcss"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spleftjoin", con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", i);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }